# Can't deploy my Xamarin Forms iOS App on physical device with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to deploy my Xamarin Forms iOS App on a physical device, but it failes and just says `A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.` I have an Apple Developer Account and I have iTunes installed, but i keep getting this error. I already looked at other peoples posts and they were all using Xcode or/and Visual Studio for Mac.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/ios-dev-no-mac/) blogpost wich I was following before to set it all up. You need Visual Studio 2022 as this bug was fixed in there.